# Как правильно настроить отображение элементов в HTML?

Tags: html, css, дерево

В общем есть HTML который выводит элементы в виде дерева. Если во вложенной папке находятся только папки, то выводит все хорошо, а когда в одной папке есть сразу и элемент и другие папки, тогда перед названиями папок возникает отступ размером с длину элемента который находится в этой же папки. Никак не получается исправить, подскажите пожалуйста, скрин прилагаю.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="treecomponents">
  <div *ngFor="let tree of SendTrees" class="treecomponent">
    <i *ngIf="tree.leaf" class="btn btn-light btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-{{tree.isExpanded ? 'minus' : 'plus'}}" (click)="onExpand(tree)"></i>
    <div class="nodeinfo">
      <span class="{{tree.leaf ? 'nodeinfo' : 'btn btn-link'}}" (click)="onSelectNode(tree)">
            {{tree.categoryName}}
            </span>
      <tree-view
        [SendTrees]="tree.nodes"
        [SelectedNode]="SelectedNode"
        (onSelectedChanged)="onSelectNode($event)"
        (onRequestNodes)="onRequestLocal($event)"
        *ngIf="tree.isExpanded">
      </tree-view>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.treecomponents {
    display:table;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.treecomponent {
    display: table-row;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.glyphicon-plus:before {
    content: "\2b";
}

.glyphicon-minus:before {
    content: "\2212";
}

.nodeinfo {
    display: table-cell;
    padding-left: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style-type: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Скрин:

[image: Скрин]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так все выводит правильно:

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="treecomponents">
  <li *ngFor="let tree of SendTrees" class="treecomponent">
    <i *ngIf="tree.leaf" class="btn btn-light btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-{{tree.isExpanded ? 'minus' : 'plus'}}" (click)="onExpand(tree)"></i>
    <a class="{{tree.leaf ? 'node' : 'btn btn-link nodetext'}}" (click)="onExpand(tree)">{{tree.categoryName}}</a>
    <div>
        <tree-view
          [SendTrees]="tree.nodes"
          [SelectedNode]="SelectedNode"
          (onSelectedChanged)="onSelectNode($event)"
          (onRequestNodes)="onRequestLocal($event)"
          *ngIf="tree.isExpanded">
        </tree-view>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.treecomponents {
  display:table;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 16px;
}

.treecomponent {
  display: table-row;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.glyphicon-plus:before {
  content: "\2b";
}

.glyphicon-minus:before {
  content: "\2212";
}

.nodeinfo {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-left: 5px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.node {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

.nodetext {
  color: #5fb611;
}
```

**Скрин:**

[image: скрин]